# Azure Custom Vision API returning different results than project portal?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-custom-vision

I've create a custom vision project to recognise characters (A, B, C...).
What is interesting: if I upload an image of a character (in this case an "N") to the vision API portal it will tell me that it is 99.9% sure it is an "N":

[image]

If however I use the client libraries to predict the very same image, I'm getting 53% that it is a "W" and only 37% that it is an "N":

[image]

- I double checked that the latest iteration is the published one
- I double checked that I'm using the correct project ID
- My endpoint is set to "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com" in the `CustomVisionPredictionClient`

The code to get the prediction on my client:

```
var client = new CustomVisionPredictionClient()
{
    ApiKey = predictionKey,
    Endpoint = endpoint
};

var result = await client.PredictImageAsync(Guid.Parse(projectId), imageStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
var prediction = result.Predictions.FirstOrDefault();
```

Where does this difference come from and how to fix because according to the tests I did by uploading images the results are close to 100% correct no matter which character image I upload?

*UPDATE:* I noticed that there was an update for the client libraries. They went from 0.12pre to 1.0stable. After the update the `PredictImageAsync` is gone and replaced with `DetectImageAsync`. This expected as an additional parameter a model name. I tried using the name of the iteration and after a while the method returns with an internal server error. So not sure what to try next.

Comment: If you doubt there is an issue in the client libraries, try to directly invoke Custom Vision REST APIs via `WebClient`. There are two different APIs `ClassifyImage` & `DetectImage` for different applied purpose, please see https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Prediction_3.0/operations/5c82db60bf6a2b11a8247c15.

Comment: You gave me the right hint! The method I was looking for is `ClassifyImage` and not `DetectImage`! Using this it works like charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above pointed my into the right direction - thanks!

The new client library has got two methods `ClassifyImage` and `DetectImage` (and various variations of them) which replace the previously used ones including `PredictImage` which I was using with the preview version of the client library.

To classify an image (which is what I wanted to do) `ClassifyImage` should of course be used. The new code looks like this and delivers an almost 100% correct prediction:

```
var client = new CustomVisionPredictionClient()
{
    ApiKey = predictionKey,
    Endpoint = endpoint
};

var result = await client.ClassifyImageAsync(Guid.Parse(projectId), "Iteration12", imageStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
var prediction = result.Predictions.FirstOrDefault();
```

- `endpoint` is the URL of the region the vision API is hosted in, in my case `https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`.
- `predictionKey` is available on the CustomVision.AI site in your project, so is the `projectId`
- The `publishedName` parameter is the name of the iteration to use (in my case "Iteration12"